# Registering custome shapes with my mxgraph librarie in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mxgraph

I'm currently building a flowchart editor with MXGraph and today I imported it into my Vue.JS project. I used NPM to install the mxgraph library and used the following code to get the apporpiated references in every file:

```
import * as mxgraph from 'mxgraph';

const {
    mxClient, mxGraph, mxUtils, mxEvent, mxConstraintHandler, mxConnectionHandler, mxEditor, mxGraphModel, mxKeyHandler, mxConstants, mxGraphView
} = mxgraph();
```

I imported my flowchart editor into Vue.js as a plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import flowchartEditor from './plugins/flowchartEditor/flowchartEditor';


import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/store'
import router from './router/router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(flowchartEditor);

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The flowchart tool has a Vue view with an route and when I go to that route the flowchart editor looks fine. The problems is that all my custom registered shapes are not working. The Start node is supposed to be round but instead all my custom shapes appear square:
[image: flowchart editor problem]

The following image is what I got with the same code but than not imported into Vue.JS but just with Webpack:
[image: flowchart editor correct]

This is the code that makes and registers the custom shapes:

```
addCustomShapes(graph) {
        //Ellipse that represents the start node
        function ellipse() {};
        ellipse.prototype = new mxEllipse();
        ellipse.prototype.constructor = ellipse;

        registerCustomShape(graph, ellipse, 'start');
    },

function registerCustomShape(graph, shape, name) {    
    mxCellRenderer.registerShape(name, shape);

    let style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultVertexStyle();
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = name;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = '#ffffff';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = '#000000';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#000000';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = '16';

    style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = '#000000';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = '#000000';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_LABEL_BACKGROUNDCOLOR] = '#ffffff';
    style['fontStyle'] = '0';
    style['fontStyle'] = '0';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = '16';
    style['startSize'] = '8';
    style['endSize'] = '8';
}
```

And then the code that sets the newly registered shape as the default shape in order to spawn the start node in:

```
setCustomShape(graph, name) {
        var style = graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultVertexStyle();
        style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = "4";

        return style
    }
```

I'm aware of the tutorial of MXGraph ([tutorial](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/shape.html)) and already did it but it got me the same result as this code.

Sorry for the long post but I find this very odd and I really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/tree/master/javascript/examples/editors

Look in this repo.

This is very simple editor example !
Simpler than draw.io editor[image]